# ClickHouse dry run query

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, acl, clickhouse, dry-run, sqlglot

I work on ClickHouse proxy which would validate and modify query before sending it to ClickHouse. To implement validation logic and I need to know what columns user request. The problem comes in when user uses `*` in select's.

For simple queries like `select * from table` I can expand `*` by myself and transform original query to e.g. `select a,b,c from table`.

Knowing table and column names and can check against user's permissions if he can access those columns. But how to deal with complicated queries with many join, subqueries etc. I was hoping that maybe there is functionality in ClickHouse which would allow to `dry-run` query before executing it, then ClickHouse would parse, analyze, optimize original SQL and produce expand one without `*`.

I couldn't find anything like that in ClickhHouse documentation. I use [sqlglot](https://github.com/tobymao/sqlglot) library to transform AST. Any ideas how resolve my problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I asked someone working in ClickHouse. You can run `EXPLAIN <query>` in the ClickHouse, but not aware of such parser independently outside ClickHouse. As this results require the table schema definition.

Comment: I think explain will only help with validation the query. The rest things like expanding '*' etc are still under question mark